# How can I disable a button if an image has not been edited?

Tags: swift, button, uiimage, isenabled

I want to try to disable a post button until an image has been chosen by the user.

However, I have a default image set as a placeholder.I have already managed to disable the post button when a textfield has not filled with information. I haven't, however, found a way to disable the button immediately.Hopefully I have explained myself.

[Here's an image of my uiview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU4JH.png)

```
func handleBlancInformation(){
    address.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
    breed.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
    phone.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)

}


@objc func textFieldDidChange() {
    guard let address = address.text, !address.isEmpty,
            let breed = breed.text, !breed.isEmpty,
            let phone = phone.text, !phone.isEmpty,
            let image = imagePosted.image, !imagePosted.isEqual("placeholder.png")
        else {
        postButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightText, for: UIControlState.normal)
            postButton.isEnabled = false
            return
    }
    postButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
    postButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need more code to give an exact solution here, but think about it this way:

Whatever method you are using for the user to choose a new image, that is where you should be enabling the "post" button.

For example, assuming you are using a UIImagePickerViewController to handle picking an image, you will want to enable the "post" button inside of this method, which is part of the **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate**:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
     if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
          //Enable button here
     } else {
          //Disable button here
     }
}
```

Comment: I used your solution + Pedro's solution to disable the postButton from the get go and then in the imagePickerController dismiss I set the code for the textFields! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Try This. Use bool for status to check weather image is selected or not.

```
var isImageSelected = false
```

`override func viewDidLoad() {
    postButton.isEnabled = false
}`

Check Image is Selected or not. Change Button Enable property while selected image.

```
if isImageSelected{
// Do Your Work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the user can click when the View is loaded and you want to prevent this right?

> but when they first enter the uiview they can click the post button

If so simply disable the button on the viewDidLoad() or in the storyboard.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    postButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

or uncheck the "Enabled" field

[image]

To verify if an user did pick an image (after the View has loaded) check Greg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51790803/1152683)

Comment: Hi Pedro! This does work! However, is there a way to apply this same logic so that, the postButton is not enabled until after the picture has been selected AND the text fields have been selected as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to make the button dissapear from the moment the user enters this tab and show it once both the uiimage and the textfields have been filled out.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

        handleBlancInformation()
        postButton.isHidden = true

    }


func handleBlancInformation(){
            address.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
            breed.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
            phone.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
            changeImageLostButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged )
        }

        @objc func textFieldDidChange() {
            guard let address = address.text, !address.isEmpty,
                    let breed = breed.text, !breed.isEmpty,
                    let phone = phone.text, !phone.isEmpty
                else {
                    postButton.isHidden = true
                    return
            }
            postButton.isHidden = false
        }


        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])

        {
            print("did Finish Picking Media")
            if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
                selectedImage = image
                imagePosted.image = image
            }

            else {

                postButton.isHidden = true

            }
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

                self.handleBlancInformation()

            })
        }
```